# RobotFramework documentation with Sphinx

Tags: python, robotframework, documentation, python-sphinx

I have small issue with creating automatic documentation for RobotFramework resources in Sphinx.

I've found two plugins:

- `sphinxcontrib_robotdoc`,
- `sphinxcontrib_robotframework`.

But `sphinxcontrib_robotdoc` is a very old solution and looks like s**t. So I want to check the second solution but it doesn't work.

conf.py:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))


# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'example RF documentation'
author = 'CG'
release = '0.0.1'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc',
              'm2r2',
              'autodocsumm',
              'sphinxcontrib_robotframework'
              ]

autodoc_default_flags = ['members', 'undoc-members', 'inherited-members']
autodoc_default_options = {
    'autosummary': True,
}

source_suffix = ['.rst', '.md']

templates_path = ['_templates']

exclude_patterns = []


sphinxcontrib_robotframework_enabled = True
sphinxcontrib_robotframework_quiet = True
sphinxcontrib_robotframework_variables = {
    "VARIABLE": "value"
}

# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------
html_theme = 'sphinx_rtd_theme'
master_doc = 'index'
```

index.rst:

```
example RF documentation
============================
.. toctree::
   :caption: Table of content
   :maxdepth: 3
   :glob:

   interfaces/*
   changelog/*
   example/*
```

interface.rst:

```
example RF documentation
============================
Keywords
********
.. automodule:: example_rf_docu
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
   :undoc-members:
.. code:: robotframework
```

creating documentation command:

```
sphinx-build -b html /home/ute/repo/example_rf_docu/docs/source/ /home/ute/repo/example_rf_docu/doc_files/
```

command output:

```
Running Sphinx v4.1.2
WARNING: while setting up extension sphinxcontrib_robotframework: directive 'code' is already registered, it will be overridden
loading pickled environment... done
[autosummary] generating autosummary for: changelog/changelog.rst, example/example.rst, index.rst, interfaces/interface.rst
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 0 source files that are out of date
updating environment: 0 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
looking for now-outdated files... none found
no targets are out of date.
build succeeded, 1 warning.

The HTML pages are in doc_files.
```

In output we can see
`[autosummary] generating autosummary for: changelog/changelog.rst, example/example.rst, index.rst, interfaces/interface.rst` and it's true every page from the list is generated properly:

- index: looks good (everything looks like I've planned),
- changelog: looks good (generate page based on changelog of whole project),
- example: looks good (it's empty because I haven't added any examples)
- interfaces: looks wrong, because contains only information about members, inherited-members and undoc-members like i set in `interface.rst` for whole project (**init**.py in main project directory) and contains no information about RobotFramework keywords from any RobotFramework file from project. And that's my small issue.

Any ideas what can I improve this and make it work.

Comment: What is the "small issue"? What exactly do you mean by "but it doesn't work"?

Comment: Interfaces page looks wrong, because contains only information about members, inherited-members and undoc-members like i set in `interface.rst` for whole project (__init__.py in main project directory) and contains no information about RobotFramework keywords from any RobotFramework file from project. And that's my small issue. 

I completed my question with above information.

Comment: Did you follow step 3 in https://sphinxcontrib-robotframework.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#getting-started? It looks like you omitted your Robot Framework tests. Either that or you need to include the docstring of `taf.rfrl.uuf4all` in your question for us to help further.

Comment: Hi, 
`taf.rfrl.uuf4all` is a code which left from "only python code repository" and i forgot to change it. I want to generate documentation based on files which are in repository not copy it from source (.robot file). Because if I copy code from `.robot` file to `interface.rst` RobotFramework is nice and colourful but it probably should work differently.